# I am using ubuntu on ESXI 5.0 but on adding the usb I am unable to view the usb or access it

Tags: esxi

I'm using ubuntu 10.04 as a guest on ESXI 5.0 but when i connected a usb device using connect to usb device I am unable to view or access my device.

How do I connect a device, and how do I get a list of connected devices? lsusbd does not give me a list of connected devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
dmesg | tail
```

just after connecting the usb. and check where it is getting connected. Then try mounting the usb manually.

Comment: hi , restarting the machine works.